# Email reminder dates older than today

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I have a sharepoint list I want to set so any dates older than today are compiled into an email and emailed with the 'title' column

If I go to the list and select Power Automate I can set a reminder for dates in the future - I'd like to mirror this for a reminder for any dates older than today.  If possible I would like to do it for multiple columns but unsure if this is possible.

Dates are UK time too, and title column is "Work Due" in that format with the spaces

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can use a Filter Query for this in your Get Items. You can use a less than operator and compare you field value with the [startofDay](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#startOfDay) and [utcNow](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#utcNow) functions.

Below is an example with the Created Field

```
Created lt '@{startOfDay(utcNow())}'
```

[image]